# Couldn't able to change the color and thickness of divider line MaterialUI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

Here is my code in codesandbox  https://codesandbox.io/s/red-sea-hc4l34?file=/demo.tsx. I have to change the thickness and color of the separator. I checked some examples but nothing is working for me somehow. I'm able to change the color of the text but the line. Please guide me on this. I'm new to MaterialUI

Comment: change `thick` to `1px` etc

Answer (score 0):

The MUI divider used `::before` and `::after` pseudo-selectors for the top and bottom lines respectively.

By inspecting the DOM with the developer tools, you can assert that the following style changes will give you the desired effects.

```
const Grid = styled(MuiGrid)(({ theme }) => ({
  width: '100%',
  ...theme.typography.body2,
  '& [role="separator"]': {
    '&::before, &::after': {
      borderColor: 'red',
      borderWidth: theme.spacing(0.5),
    },
    margin: theme.spacing(0, 2),
    color: 'red',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
}));
```